# Transfer app iPhone to iPad with WiFi but no internet connection?

Tags: ios, airdrop

So I’m at the airport and the WiFi has no internet connection. I installed an app on my phone using my data connection, but I would like to use/install it on my iPad. I was able to air drop a link to the app on the App Store to the iPad, but of course that didn’t work because the link wouldn’t load. Is there a way to air drop the app somehow? Can I like, zip up the app and air drop that file? How is airdrop connecting? Bluetooth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to install any iOS app is from the App Store. [in this situation Configurator isn't an option.]

I'm afraid there's no way out of your situation, short of finding a working connection... which your phone could perhaps provide, using its built-in hot-spot.

Answer (score 1):

What about using your iPhone as a hotspot (if the carrier allows it) so the iPad can download it.

Sure it may eat up your quota if you have a small amount but it should work.

Comment: I did think of that, but Sprint doesn’t allow it, at least not with my plan.

Comment: @hepcat72 wow, that would be a formidable option. You might want to check and see if they offer it or if possible change carriers.